# How does one make a website page scroll down - while holding down the mouse button - instead of scrolling?

Tags: html, button, mouse, move

Want to make the page move downward - as if a user were scrolling with the mouse wheel.

Want to write in code

1. When Left Mouse Button Down (is pressed and held) - (anywhere on the page) - page moves down in an accelerated way - think exponential curves

I used to eff with video game dev - and really like to think of things from 0-100 - wondering if anyone out there has found a way to do this?

Thank you everyone - Love you guys - AG

here's an example of what i'm trying to do

https://agbabbbycakes.github.io/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

asked Chat GPT to do it - and it did it!

Here is how to "make the page scroll down faster and faster depending on how long a user presses down the mouse button anywhere on the page"

HTML

```
<body onmousedown="startScroll()" onmouseup="stopScroll()">
<!-- Your content goes here -->
```

JS

```
  let intervalId;
let scrollSpeed = 10; // starting scroll speed

function startScroll() {
    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        window.scrollBy(0, scrollSpeed);
        scrollSpeed += 1; // increment scroll speed
    }, 50);
}

function stopScroll() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    scrollSpeed = 10; // reset scroll speed
}
```